# Access org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text from Overridden createWindowContents

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have overridden the method `createWindowContents` in my `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` class.

I put a Text box at the banner I created so that user could insert an URL that would be readed in an Action.

My problem is that I don't know how to access this field from another View or another Action. Can I access it via `PlatformUI` object or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can just store it in a static variable (don't forget to check if it is disposed before accessing it).